# Sending Inputstream in spring integration

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have a project where I want to sending a pdf file to an ftp server.

I am creating the file using pdfbox and changing it to an Inputstream and then I was to pass this input scream value to a remote FTP and save it as .pdf.

I have the below code but not sure how I can pass the data to the outbound adapter.

```
 @Bean
public IntegrationFlow localToFtpFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("toFtpChannel")
            .handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(sf())
                    .remoteDirectory("/ftp/forklift_checklist"))
            .get();
}

@MessagingGateway
public interface MyGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "toFtpChannel")
    void sendToFtp(InputStream file);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what why is the question.

What you have so far is OK:

1. You call that `sendToFtp()` gateway's method with an `InputStream` for a local file.
2. The `Ftp.outboundAdapter(sf()` is based on the `this.remoteFileTemplate.send(message, this.mode)` operation which really supports an `InputStream` for a request payload:

   ```
   else if (payload instanceof InputStream) {
            return new StreamHolder((InputStream) payload, "InputStream payload");
        }
   ```

So, share with us, please, what the problem are you observing with your configuration?

Perhaps you are looking into a `fileName` to give for that data while saving to FTP. Consider to have another gateway argument as a `@Header(FileHeaders.FILENAME) String fileName`. The `RemoteFileTemplate` relies on a `DefaultFileNameGenerator` which looks into that header by default.

Comment: I was facing issue to call the method in the interface so I had to annotate MyGateway with `@Service` so I can call it from another service as it was giving cannot autowire. Also was wondering about to pass the file name so thanks for mention it to me on how to pass it as parameter... all is well now :) @Artem Bilan